# Preprocessor directive to detect running on macOS using the Designed for iPad target

Tags: ios, swift, macos, preprocessor-directive

Apple provides a runtime `isiOSAppOnMac` property of `ProcessInfo` to detect if running on a Mac using the `Designed for iPad` target.

I'd much rather use a preprocessor directive than having to do runtime checks. When using a `MacCatalyst` target this works:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
```

I've tried both:

```
#if os(macOS)
#if !os(iOS)
```

But those do not work for `Designed for iPad`. This actually seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a better way?

```
#if arch(arm64) && os(iOS) && !targetEnvironment(simulator)
    print("Designed for iPad on a Mac")
#endif
```

Comment: The problem is that you are not doing a separate build for the Mac. You do one build for iOS and that's it. So compiler checks won't help. Only a runtime check can determine if your iPad app is actually being used on an Apple Silicon Mac.

Comment: Oh very good point. My directive also works on an iPad, darn it. Well, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that you do not perform a separate compilation for a Mac version of the app in this case. It's simply a matter of the iPad app running on an Apple Silicon Mac. Since there's only the one iOS build, you can't use compiler flags. Your only option is to use runtime checks to determine if the iPad app is currently running on a Mac.

Of course if you later build a Mac version of the app using Mac Catalyst (so you can support Intel Macs in addition to Apple Silicon Macs), then you can use compiler flags (as you pointed out in the question) since you have two builds, one for the Mac (via Mac Catalyst), and one for iOS.

Comment: I am trying to use Mac Catalyst now, but I need for it to only support Apple Silicon. Seems possible with `xcodebuild` and specify `arm64` for `arch`.

Comment: Curious why you want to exclude Intel Macs if you go to the trouble of using Mac Catalyst.

Comment: Because CoreML inference is ten times slower without the Apple Neural Engine, and I would much rather have a separate target so I can use preprocessor directives instead of runtime checks. Basically, I want a Mac specific target but don't want to support Intel Macs.